# Inconsistent Unexpected Token: <

Tags: mocha.js, reactjs

I have a unit test in mocha for a react component that works:

```js
var should = require('should');

require('./testdom')('<html><body></body></html>');

describe('update-button', function () {
  var queryA = {some object};
  var queryB = {some slightly different object};
  var reportA = {currentQuery: JSON.stringify(queryA)};
  var reportB = {currentQuery: JSON.stringify(queryB)};
  var React = require('react/addons');
  var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
  var UpdateButtons = require('../client/src/js/components/UpdateButtons');

  it('returns apply button', function() {

    var updateButton = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <UpdateButtons
        query={queryA}
        defaultQuery={JSON.stringify(queryB)}
        report={reportB} />
    );


    var update = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(updateButton, 'update');
    should.exist(update.getDOMNode().children);
    update.props.children.should.equal('Apply');

  });

  it('returns default button', function() {
    var updateButton = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <UpdateButtons
        query={queryB}
        defaultQuery={JSON.stringify(queryA)}
        report={reportB} />
    );

    var update = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(updateButton, 'setdefault');
    should.exist(update.getDOMNode().children);
    update.props.children.should.equal('Make Default');
  });

});
```

Mocha deals with it fine and the two tests pass.

And then I have another test, where I just change the name of the the component and add slightly different functionality:

```js
var should = require('should');

require('./testdom')('<html><body></body></html>');
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var AllocationChart = require('../client/src/js/components/AllocationChart');

function emptyFunction() {
  return "fired";
}

describe('allocation-chart', function () {
  var values = [{"x":0,"y":0.0007445807134429661,"pvalue":0.23962495642627535},{"x":1,"y":0.0017470479717729415,"pvalue":0.06222155778588356},{"x":2,"y":0.001213604360619125,"pvalue":0.3751442982987042},{"x":3,"y":-0.0007938410728732803,"pvalue":0.6306601384568038},{"x":4,"y":-0.0013313112686847983,"pvalue":0.4930399112767866},{"x":5,"y":-0.0002447714978416893,"pvalue":0.906972528582401},{"x":6,"y":0.0008058818608920326,"pvalue":0.6581667787665311}];
  var valueExtent = [-0.5, 0.5];

  it('is created', function() {

    var sparkline = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <AllocationChart
        key={1}
        highlightbar={emptyFunction}
        newHighlightbar={emptyFunction}
        values={values}
        valueExtent={valueExtent}
        highlightRow={emptyFunction}
        deHighlightRow={emptyFunction} />
    );

    var chart = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(sparkline, 'allocationChart');
    chart.length.should.equal(1);
    should.exist(chart.getDOMNode());

    var sparklineBins = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(sparkline, 'sparklineBin');
    sparklineBins.length.should.equal(7);

  });

  it('fires a hover event', function() {
    var sparkline = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <AllocationChart
        key={1}
        highlightbar={emptyFunction}
        newHighlightbar={emptyFunction}
        values={values}
        valueExtent={valueExtent}
        highlightRow={emptyFunction}
        deHighlightRow={emptyFunction} />
    );

    var sparklineBins = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(sparkline, 'sparklineBin');

    var responseA = TestUtils.Simulate.mouseover(sparklineBins[0]);
    var responseB = TestUtils.Simulate.mouseout(sparklineBins[0]);

    responseA.should.equal("fired");
    responseB.should.equal("fired");

  });
```

But instead of working, this returns the following error:

```
      <AllocationChart
      ^
Warning: Unexpected token < Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And I have no idea how or why or how this could happen.

Comment: What are you using to transform your JSX into JavaScript?

Comment: I'm following the compiler.js pattern here: http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/14/testing-react-web-apps-with-mocha/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell; my best guess is that the JSX for the second file isn't being transformed to JavaScript before it gets to Mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elijah [identified the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279942/1906307). Here's is a solution:

1. Move `compiler.js` out of the test directory so that Mocha won't load it as a test file.
2. Create a `mocha.opts` file *inside the test directory*. It should  contain:

   ```
   --compilers .:compiler.js
   ```

   The module path passed to `--compilers` is relative to the directory where Mocha runs. By the way [hammerlab.org](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/14/testing-react-web-apps-with-mocha/) is clear that the compiler is to be loaded using `--compilers`. The use of `mocha.opts` avoids having to pass the parameter to RequireJS every single time.

Answer (score 0):

The method of compiling JSX as described at [hammerlab.org](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/14/testing-react-web-apps-with-mocha) places the compiler.js (which handles the JSX transformation through ReactTools.transform) in the test folder along with other tests. If the React tests are alphabetically before compiler.js, you'll get this error because it hasn't registered by the time it got to that test.

Comment: You should include a better alternative